# Prove that $\frac{2-a}{a+\sqrt{bc+abc}}+\frac{2-b}{b+\sqrt{ca+abc}}+\frac{2-c}{c+\sqrt{ab+abc}} \geq \frac{2-a}{a+2}+\frac{2-b}{b+2}+\frac{2-c}{c+2}$

Tags: inequality

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4415209/954997) question, [Calvin Lin](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/54563/calvin-lin) points out that the OP has made the incorrect assumption that $\frac{2-a}{a+\sqrt{bc+abc}}+\frac{2-b}{b+\sqrt{ca+abc}}+\frac{2-c}{c+\sqrt{ab+abc}} \geq \frac{2-a}{a+2}+\frac{2-b}{b+2}+\frac{2-c}{c+2}$ because $a+\sqrt{bc+abc}=a+\sqrt{4-a(b+c)}\le a+2
$ where $a,b,c\ge0$ and $ab+bc+ca+abc=4$. Assuming that this assumption is correct, [learning123](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/905694/learning123) provides a solution to the original question. However, this assumption still remains unproven. So my question is how can we prove it?

$2$ approaches come to mind - casework and proving the original question using an approach that doesn't rely on this initial assumption.

I think there are problems with both approaches. With casework, there seem to be many cases to consider which include all the permutations of $a \geq 2$ or $a < 2$, $b \geq 2$ or $b < 2$ and $a \geq b$ or $a < b$. But even if we systematically write down each case, there are many challenges. Firstly, it is not obvious what the range of values for $c$ will be in each case, and even if we have that information, considering whether our assumption is true given these new domains is a challenge in itself. This is probably equivalent to solving many difficult inequality problems just to ultimately solve $1$. The second approach seems more reasonable to me than the first, but it will still require an ingenious strategy that is not immediately obvious to me.

Considering all of this,

> How can we prove
> $\frac{2-a}{a+\sqrt{bc+abc}}+\frac{2-b}{b+\sqrt{ca+abc}}+\frac{2-c}{c+\sqrt{ab+abc}}
>  \geq \frac{2-a}{a+2}+\frac{2-b}{b+2}+\frac{2-c}{c+2}$ where
> $a,b,c\ge0$ and $ab+bc+ca+abc=4$?

Comment: FYI You're asking the same question as Mars. IE The RHS is exactly 1.

Comment: @CalvinLin Yes, I am aware. I chose to ask a separate question as all of the above would not fit in a single comment.

Comment: For the casework, you just have to deal with WLOG $ a > 2$.  Note that we cannot have 2 values both being $> 2$, since that gives $ab > 4$.

Comment: @CalvinLin Hmm, didn’t think of that. A solution still isn’t obvious to me but I'll try to play around a bit.

Comment: Agreed that there isn't an obvious solution. $\quad$ To clarify, the incorrect assumption is that $ (2-a) / ( a + \sqrt{bc+abc} ) \geq (2-a) / (a+2)$.  When we sum up the cyclic versions, it is possible that the differences cancel out.

Answer (score 1):

*Alternative proof.*

Notice that $$(b+c-a)^2(bc+abc)=[(a+b+c)^2-4a(b+c)]\cdot[4-a(b+c)]\le [2(a+b+c)-2a(b+c)]^2,$$
$$\implies |b+c-a|\cdot\sqrt{bc+abc}\le |2(a+b+c)-2a(b+c)|. $$

Now, $|b+c-a|\ge b+c-a$ and we'll prove $$2(a+b+c)-2a(b+c)\ge 0, $$ or $$a+b+c+bc+abc-4\ge 0.$$

It's easy to get a substitution $a=\dfrac{2x}{y+z};b=\dfrac{2y}{x+z};c=\dfrac{2z}{y+x}$ where $x,y,z\ge 0: xy+yz+zx>0.$

We'll prove $a+b+c\ge ab+bc+ca$ or $$2\sum_{cyc}\frac{x}{y+z}\ge 4\sum_{cyc}\frac{yz}{(y+x)(z+x)},$$
$$\iff \sum_{cyc}x(x+y)(x+z)\ge 2\sum_{cyc}yz(z+y),$$
$$\iff x^3+y^3+z^3+3xyz\ge xy(x+y)+yz(y+z)+zx(x+z),$$which is Schur or third degree.

Thus, $a+b+c+abc+bc-4\ge ab+bc+ca+ab+bc-4\ge 0.$

And it gives that $$(b+c-a)\sqrt{bc+abc}\le 2(a+b+c)-2a(b+c) \iff 2(b+c)\sqrt{bc+abc}+2a(b+c)\le (a+b+c)(2+\sqrt{bc+abc}),$$
or $$\frac{2+\sqrt{bc+abc}}{a+\sqrt{bc+abc}}\ge \frac{2(b+c)}{a+b+c} \tag{*}.$$
Take cyclic sum on $(*)$ and we're done.