# Finding $\small{\min\limits_{a+b+c=2(ab+bc+ca)}\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{ab}+\dfrac{1}{bc}+1}.}$

Tags: inequality, radicals, cauchy-schwarz-inequality

If $a,b,c>0 : a+b+c=2(ab+bc+ca),$ then find the minimal value$$P=\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{ab}+\dfrac{1}{bc}+1}+\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{bc}+\dfrac{1}{ca}+1}+\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{ca}+\dfrac{1}{ab}+1}.$$
By set $a=b=c=1/2,$ I got $P\ge 9.$

I've tried to use classical inequality based on this equality case. For example, $$4.\frac{1}{4ab}+4.\frac{1}{4cb}+1\ge 9\sqrt[9]{\frac{1}{(4ab)^4.(4bc)^4}}$$
Similarly, it's enough to prove $$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt[18]{\frac{1}{(4ab)^4.(4bc)^4}}\ge 3$$
Also by AM-GM, it remains to prove $abc\le \dfrac{1}{8}.$

I can't go further because I am still stuck to show $abc\le \dfrac{1}{8}$ is true or false.

Hope you can help me continue my idea. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Proof.**

By your idea to prove $P\ge 9,$ we can apply AM-GM inequality as
$$2\sqrt{a+b+abc}\le \sqrt{\frac{ab}{c}}(c+1)+\frac{a+b+abc}{c+1}\sqrt{\frac{c}{ab}}=\frac{ab+bc+ca}{(c+1)\sqrt{abc}}+2\sqrt{abc}.$$
It implies that
$$\frac{ab+bc+ca}{(c+1)\sqrt{abc}}\ge \frac{2(a+b)}{\sqrt{a+b+abc}+\sqrt{abc}},$$or
$$\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{ab}+\dfrac{1}{bc}+1} \ge \dfrac{2a+2b+ca+cb-ab}{ab+bc+ca} \tag{1}.$$
Take cyclic sum on $(1),$ we get
\begin{align*}
 &\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{ab}+\dfrac{1}{bc}+1}+\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{bc}+\dfrac{1}{ca}+1}+\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{ca}+\dfrac{1}{ab}+1}\\
 &\ge \dfrac{4(a+b+c)+ab+bc+ca}{ab+bc+ca}\\
 &\ge \dfrac{9(ab+bc+ca)}{ab+bc+ca}=9
\end{align*}
Hence, the proof is done.

In conclusion: Minimum $P=9$ at $a=b=c=\dfrac{1}{2}.$

Comment: Yes, of course! :)

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg It turns out we got same goal :)

Comment: Good one. I accept it!

Comment: Nice. (1) is a way of isolated fudging. (Already upvoted one week ago.)

Comment: By the way, the isolated fudging $\sqrt{\dfrac{1}{ab}+\dfrac{1}{bc}+1}
\ge \frac{4a^2 + b^2 + 4c^2 + 6(ab + bc + ca)}{(a + b + c)^2}$ also works. But my proof for this is not nice.

Comment: @RiverLi Your isolated fudging seems interesting.

Comment: @TATAbox Here is an easy isolated fudging: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4415209/frac2-aa-sqrtbcabc-frac2-bb-sqrtcaabc-frac2-cc-sqrtaba/4416853#comment10230616_4416853

Answer (score 2):

Let $ab=z$, $ac=y$ and $bc=x$.

Thus, the condition gives $$\frac{xy+xz+yz}{\sqrt{xyz}}=2(x+y+z),$$ which gives:
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{1}{ab}+\frac{1}{ac}+1}=\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\left(\frac{1}{z}+\frac{1}{y}\right)\cdot\frac{4(xyz)(x+y+z)^2}{(xy+xz+yz)^2}+1}$$ and we need to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{4x(y+z)(x+y+z)^2}{(xy+xz+yz)^2}+1}\geq9,$$
which is homogeneous already, which says that we can assume  $x+y+z=xy+xz+yz.$

Indeed, let $k(x+y+z)=xy+xz+yz,$ $x=kp$, $y=kq$ and $z=kr$.

Thus, $p+q+r=pq+pr+qr$ and we need to prove that:
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{4x(y+z)(x+y+z)^2}{(xy+xz+yz)^2}+1}\geq9$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{4kp(kq+kr)(kp+kq+kr)^2}{(k^2pq+k^2pr+k^2pr)^2}+1}\geq9$$ or
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{4p(q+r)(p+q+r)^2}{(pq+pr+qr)^2}+1}\geq9,$$ which is the same inequality.

Thus, by C-S
$$\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{\frac{4x(y+z)(x+y+z)^2}{(xy+xz+yz)^2}+1}=\sum_{cyc}\sqrt{4x(y+z)+1}=$$
$$=\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}\sqrt{(y+z-x)^2+4x(y+z))(1+4x(y+z))}}{x+y+z}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}(y+z-x+4x(y+z))}{x+y+z}=9.$$

Comment: When I saw this Question , I knew that you would answer it shortly ! When you say "Thus, the condition gives ..." I could make out that Equality. When you later say "Now, let ...." , I unable to see that Equality. It seems to imply $a+b+c=1/a+1/b+1/c$ : What am I missing there ?

Comment: @Prem  After homogenization we can assume that $x+y+z=xy+xz+yz.$ See please better my solution.

Comment: Oh ok , that makes sense , thank you. I think that is like change of variables $x+y+z=XY+YZ+ZX$ though homogenization might be Equivalent.

Comment: I still didn't understand the assumption. Can someone explain what happened here?

Comment: @Shubhav Jain I added something. See now. I hope now it's clear.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Perfect! I got it. Thanks!

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg Your solution is impressive!

Answer (score 1):

Counter example for $abc \leq \frac{1}{8}$ is simple. Observe that $\left(a,b,c\right) = \left(\frac{1}{4}, 3, \frac{7}{22}\right)$ is a solution and $abc = \frac{21}{88}$ which is greater than $\frac{1}{8}$.

Comment: Obviously, multiple examples of this kind would be available. Nothing is special about the one taken here.